# Nvidia driver isnt recognized after ubuntu software update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, with ah gpu by Nvidia, GeForce 1660Ti.

I dont know if this is a relevant information, but I use with a dual boot with Windows.

When I first installed everything, I had to change the driver configurations on ubuntu so the gpu could be recognized.

It worked perfectly by several months, but recently with a regular update of ubuntu my gpu drivers are not being recognized, I tried everything that I did for the first time but it didn't work.

Any suggestions? I'm kind of lost because I have no skills to deal with ubuntu problems.

output  of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is

```
29:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2182 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Device 196e:1312
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
29:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aeb (rev a1)
```

Comment: What are the drivers, how  did you install them?

Comment: nvidia driver 435 and 440 are appearing for me right now, to be honest I dont remember how did I installed them in that time.

Comment: What do you mean by "them"? You can't have installed both.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Actually I dont remember of install both of them, but when I go to Drivers, both appear for me. Actually I don't know if even one of them are already installed or if they are just appearing there. sorry I'm quite slow with those things, the output of the command are in the question now. whats next?

Comment: Nothing is installed. Select the 440 driver and it will be installed.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have an LTS kernel you have to install the Nvidia-lts version of the driver,  you should uninstall the other one and try with the LTS one

Comment: I dont know exactly how to find and install such driver, always when I google those informations it is quite confuse, could you help me?

Comment: This is wrong. @BrunoMagacho You don't need to find anything. the system already suggested the drivers.